# Finding the smallest sum of the difference of A[i] and a constant

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sum, constants

For an assignment I need to solve a mathmatical problem. I narrowed it down to the following:

Let `A[1, ... ,n]` be an array of `n` integers.

Let `y` be an integer constant.

Now, I have to write an algorithm that finds the minimum of `M(y)` in `O(n)` time:

`M(y) = Sum |A[i] - y|, i = 1 to n`. Note that I not just take `A[i] - y`, but the absolute value `|A[i] - y|`.

For clarity, I also put this equation in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=M(y)%20%3D%20sum%20%7CA(i)%20-%20y%7C,%20i%20%3D%201%20to%20n).

I have considered least squares method, but this will not yield the minimum of `M(y)` but more of an average value of `A`, I think. As I'm taking the absolute value of `A[i] - y`, there is also no way I can differentiate this function to `y`. Also I can't just come up with any algorithm because I have to do it in `O(n)` time. Also, I believe there can be more correct answers for `y` in some cases, in that case, the value of `y` must be equal to one of the integer elements of `A`.

This has really been eating me for a whole week now and I still haven't figured it out. Can anyone please teach me the way to go or point me in the right direction? I'm stuck. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You are looking for the median. I'm going to demonstrate it in an answer.

Comment: @Nelxiost is right. Setting `y` to the median of `A` will result in minimum `M(y)`. You can calculate the median with *median of medians* in linear time.

Comment: Thank you so much! But how would I be able to prove this method?

Comment: There are more ways of finding the minimum of a function than finding the root of its first derivative (which is not possible in this case as you observed). Instead, you want to find a location where the derivative switches from negative to positive. And since the absolute function has either -1 or +1 derivative, it is pretty easy to show that the median is the minimum (observe what happens to the total derivative when you cross an entry in `A`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to pick a y for which `M(y) = sum(abs(A[i] - y))` is minimal. Let's assume every `A[i]` is positive (it does not change the result, because the problem is invariant by translation).

Let's start with two simple observations. First, if you pick y such that `y < min(A)` or `y > max(A)`, you end up with a greater value for M(y) than if you picked y such that `min(A) <= y <= max(A)`. Also, there is a unique local minimum or range of minima of A (M(y) is convex).

So we can start by picking some y in the interval `[min(A) .. max(A)]` and try to move this value around so that we get a smaller M(y). To make things easier to understand, let's sort A and pick a i in `[1 .. n]` (so `y = A[i]`).

There are three cases to consider.

If `A[i+1] > A[i]`, and either {n is odd and `i < (n+1)/2`} or {n is even and `i < n/2`}, then `M(A[i+1]) < M(A[i])`.
This is because, going from `M(A[i])` to `M(A[i+1])`, the number of terms that decrease (that is `n-i`) is greater than the number of terms that increase (that is `i`), and the increase or decrease is always of the same amount. In the case where n is odd, `i < (n+1)/2 <=> 2*i < n+1 <=> 2*i < n`, because 2*i is even (thus necessarily smaller than a larger even number from which we subtract one).
In more formal terms, `M(A[i]) = sum(A[i]-A[s]) + sum(A[g]-A[i])`, where s and g represent indices such that `A[s] < A[i]` and `A[g] > A[i]`. So if `A[i+1] > A[i]`, then `M(A[i+1]) = sum(A[i]-A[s]) + i*(A[i+1]-A[i]) + sum(A[g]-A[i]) - (n-i)*(A[i+1]-A[i]) = M(A[i]) + (2*i-n)*(A[i+1]-A[i])`. Since `2*i < n` and `A[i+1] > A[i]`, `(2*i-n)*(A[i+1]-A[i]) < 0`, so `M(A[i+1]) < M(A[i])`.

Similarly, if `A[i-1] < A[i]`, and either {n is odd and `i > (n+1)/2`} or {n is even and `i > (n/2)+1`}, then `M(A[i-1]) > M(A[i])`.

Finally, if {n is odd and `i = (n+1)/2`} or {n is even and `i = (n/2) or (n/2)+1`}, then you have a minimum, because decrementing or incrementing i will eventually lead you to the first or second case, respectively. There are leftover possible values for i, but all of them lead to A[i] being a minimum too.

The median of A is exactly the value A[i] where i satisfies the last case. If the number of elements in A is odd, then you have exactly one such value, `y = A[(n+1)/2]` (but possibly multiple indices for it) ; if it's even, then you have a range (which may contain just one integer) of such values, `A[n/2] <= y <= A[n/2+1]`.

There is a standard C++ algorithm that can help you find the median in O(n) time : [nth_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element). If you are using another language, look up [the median of medians algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) (which Nico Schertler [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756662/finding-the-smallest-sum-of-the-difference-of-ai-and-a-constant#comment66809757_39756662)) or even [introselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introselect) (which is what nth_element typically uses).

Comment: @NicoSchertler Looks like I went too fast. I redid the whole demonstration. Hopefully it's now correct and more rigorous. I don't know, it's getting late. Feel free to improve it.

Comment: +Nelxiost, thank you so much for elaborating on this so intensively! You should give me your paypal address so I can give you a beer :)

Comment: @Anteino Heh, it's not that much. Just consider marking the answer so the question doesn't show up as unanswered.